# Install gseapy in R PackagesNotFoundError

Tags: python, r, conda, miniconda

I would like to run gseapy in rstudio as I need to perform some pathway analysis using GSEA_InContext. This is what I have:

```
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv('/home/user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate')
conda_install("r-reticulate", "gseapy")
```

However, it throws me error as:

```
'/home/user/.local/share/r-miniconda/bin/conda' 'install' '--yes' '--name' 'r-reticulate' '-c' 'conda-forge' 'gseapy'
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - gseapy
Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


Error: one or more Python packages failed to install [error code 1]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bioinformatics tools are generally hosted on [Bioconda](http://bioconda.github.io), and that includes [`gseapy`](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/gseapy). In the future, please [search Anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search) to find Conda package builds.

To install with `reticulate`, would be something like

```
conda_install("gseapy", channel=c('conda-forge', 'bioconda', 'defaults'))
```

I don't think you should be also installing `r-reticulate` (an R package) in the Python environment. Personally, I've found keeping environments granular (task-based) and not mixing Python and R in the same environment leads to a smoother user experience.